# How to add new elements without re-rendering whole list with React

Tags: javascript, dom, reactjs

I'm working on simple stream app. I have list of posts and this list can receive updates, which will display on top of it.

The problem is on each new post receive React rerenders the whole list of elements. I've made simple example for it.

Is there any way to avoid this behaviour?
I've seen the ***dynamic-children*** topic on React docs, but in example, as you see, I have all children updated anyway.

```js
class Post extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log('rerendered post', this.props.reactKey);
    return (
      <li>{this.props.post.text}</li>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {posts: [
      {id: '00001', text: 'First one'},
      {id: '00002',text: 'Second one'},
      {id: '00003',text: 'Third one'}
    ]};
  }

  addPost() {
    const posts = this.state.posts;
    posts.unshift({id: '00004', text: 'New post'});
    this.setState({posts: posts});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.addPost.bind(this)}>Add Post</button>
        <ul>
          {this.state.posts.map((post, index) => {
            return (<Post post={post} key={post.id} reactKey={index} />);
          })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
</body>
```

**The solution**

The problem was that I used index of .map function is a key for each list component instead of unique key. And because after adding new element to list all indexes changes to +1, so the first post becomes the second, all my posts have re-rendered.
So at first, check you use unique keys across all list elements :-)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with renders getting called multiple times, React will only update the DOM for things that actually change. render gets called on each component to figure out if anything has changed. If you know for sure in your component that it should even attempt to call render (which I reiterate is fine), you can use `shouldComponentUpdate`

Comment: The problem is I don't need to re-render old posts, because there are some functions with API call's and etc.
I want them just to stay as they are and only add and render new posts.

Comment: Then you must use `shouldComponentUpdate` to determine if any relevant props have changed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Work that needs to be done only once should be done in a lifecycle method that is guaranteed to run only once, like [`componentDidMount`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#mounting-componentdidmount). As the docs suggest:

> If you want to integrate with other JavaScript frameworks, set timers using setTimeout or setInterval, or send AJAX requests, perform those operations in this method.

I added logging to `componentDidMount` in your snippet to show rendering happens many times, but `componentDidMount` is called only once per instance.

```js
class Post extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('mounted post', this.props.id);
  }

  render() {
    console.log('rerendered post', this.props.id);
    return (
      <li>{this.props.post.text}</li>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.nextId = 4;
    this.state = {
      posts: [
        {id: 1, text: 'First one'},
        {id: 2,text: 'Second one'},
        {id: 3,text: 'Third one'},
      ],
    };
  }

  addPost() {
    const posts = this.state.posts;
    posts.unshift({id: this.nextId, text: 'Post ' + this.nextId});
    this.nextId++;
    this.setState({posts: posts});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.addPost.bind(this)}>Add Post</button>
        <ul>
          {this.state.posts.map((post, index) => {
            return (<Post post={post} key={post.id} id={post.id} />);
          })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you Ross. The actual problem was (because I'm new to React) that I didn't use unique keys across all list elements. I've used just map function index value and of course after adding new element to list all my elements have re-rendered because key value for each of them was changed.