# How Do You Create Multiple, Simultaneous and Identical Animations in React Native?

Tags: react-native, animation, expo, react-animated

**What Currently Happens**

- There is an image of a gun. You click the gun, an animation fires with a single bullet.
- You click the gun again. The original bullet animation disappears and new bullet comes out of the gun.

**What I Want to Happen**

- You click the gun multiple times and multiple bullets are seen animating. The original bullet does not go away until the animation has run its course.

Is this possible with React Native? Can you point me in the right direction?

Here's the snippet of the animation code if it helps...

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Animated, Easing, Dimensions, Image } from 'react-native'

let animatedValue = new Animated.Value(0)    

export let animateHappy = () => {
    console.log('animate happy run')
    animatedValue.setValue(0)
    Animated.timing(
        animatedValue,
        {
        toValue: 1,
        duration: 800,
        useNativeDriver: true,
        easing: Easing.linear
        }
    )
    .start()
}

export function HappyAnimation() {

    let windowWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width
    let windowHeight = (Dimensions.get('window').height)

    const movingMargin = animatedValue.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, 1],
        outputRange: [0, (windowHeight/2.4)]
    })

    const movingXHappy = animatedValue.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, 1],
        outputRange: [0, -90]
    })

return (
    <Animated.Image
    source={require('./assets/happy.png')} 
        style={{
        transform: [
        {translateY: (movingMargin)},
        {translateX: (movingXHappy)}
        ],
        zIndex: 0,
        marginLeft: 144,
        marginTop: (windowHeight*.35),
        height: 14,
        width: 14,}} 
    />
)
}

export default HappyAnimation
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to instantiate, render, and trigger a new HappyAnimation component each time the gun fires. Consider using some type of delay to delete the component after the animation finishes.

Comment: Thanks! To trigger a new HappyAnimation component, I'm thinking I'd (1) create an array, (2) add an entry to the array any time the gun is clicked, (3) use that array to render components (the bullets), and (4) destroy the bullet when the animation finishes. am i going in the right direction?

Comment: Yes, exactly! Make sure that the array elements have unique key identifiers, so they don't rerender when you delete elements.

Comment: I gave that approach a shot, but I'm getting stuck with a Catch-22. If I use state to keep track of the array, then anytime I update the array, it causes all the bullets to re-render. If I don't use state, then I add to the array, but it doesn't re-render.

Comment: You have to use unique keys for each array element. And NOT the index. Check out this thread for a similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39082597/how-to-add-new-elements-without-re-rendering-whole-list-with-react

Comment: Ohh yea, that makes sense! I'll give that a shot.